# Aggregation over a few models - Django

Tags: python, database, django, django-models

I'm trying to compute the average of a field over various subsets of a queryset.

```
Player.objects.order_by('-score').filter(sex='male').aggregate(Avg('level'))
```

This works perfectly!

---

**But...** if I try to compute it for the **top 50 players** it does not work.

```
Player.objects.order_by('-score').filter(sex='male')[:50].aggregate(Avg('level'))
```

This last one returns the exact same result as the query above it, which is wrong.

---

What am I doing wrong?

Help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Do you want to get the average level for the "top 50 male players" or "male players in the top 50"?  Your code suggests "top 50 male players" but your description only says "top 50 players".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
topfifty = Player.objects.order_by('-score')[:50]
Player.objects.filter(sex='male',pk__in=topfifty).aggregate(avglevel=Avg('level'))
```

edit: i haven't tested this, but i think you get the idea of where i'm going.

```
topfifty = Player.objects.order_by('-score')[:50]
ids = []
for t in topfifty:
    ids += [t.id]

Player.objects.filter(sex='male',pk__in=ids).aggregate(avglevel=Avg('level'))
```

it's kind of hackish but the best i can think of. perhaps consider filtering for male and taking the top 50 males instead of this which takes the top fifty and then filters out the males.

Comment: @Brandon: I'm confused... that returns the average level for each player? Each player has 1 level field, I'm trying to compute the average over a group of players! Anyway thanks for the answer. :)

Comment: ah i will adjust accordingly.

Comment: @Brandon: I had a slight problem with the implementation. Can you edit **topfifty** to become a list of IDs? I promise I'll tick it after that... I wouldn't have been able to come up with that :)

Comment: hmm i thought it was supposed to work the way i had it before. this is all i can think of to extract a list of ids.

Comment: You can skip that for loop and just pass in the target query set:  `...filter(sex='male', pk__in=topfifty)`.  Easier to read and you hold off on hitting the DB until the aggregate() call.

Comment: that's what i had before, but he had an issue and needed the list of ids. i'm sure there's a better way to get the ids, but that's what i could think of from memory.

Comment: Gotcha, evolving question leading to an evolving answer.  I was just trying to suggest skipping the list of ids entirely.

Answer (score 3):

Break the problem up into two logical steps; figure out the target set, perform the aggregate calculation.

```
top50_male_players = Player.objects.filter(sex='male').order_by('-score')[:50]
result = Player.objects.filter(pk__in=top50_male_players).aggregate(Avg('level'))
```

Thanks to lazy evaluation of the QuerySet it will be performed in a single DB operation.  You can play with this in the shell to verify the query counts.

```
> from django.db import connection
> connection.queries = []
> top50_male_players = Player.objects.filter(sex='male').order_by('-score')[:50]
> len(connection.queries)
0
> result = Player.objects.filter(pk__in=top50_male_players).aggregate(Avg('level'))
> len(connection.queries)
1
> result
{'level__avg': <some number>}
> len(connection.queries)
1
```

Comment: @istruble: thank for your answer! unfortunately I don't know why **pk__in=queryset** is not returning the right results. But does indeed work if I build an array of IDs instead.

Comment: That is very strange.  Are you using anything other than filter() order_by() and []/slice to come up with your `queryset` value?  I'll take another look if you paste the line you use to create `queryset` in another comment.

Answer (score -1):

Hmm. The docs say

"Slicing. As explained in Limiting QuerySets, a QuerySet can be sliced, using Python's array-slicing syntax. Usually slicing a QuerySet returns another (unevaluated) QuerySet, but Django will execute the database query if you use the "step" parameter of slice syntax." http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/

So I'd try

```
Player.objects.order_by('-score').filter(sex='male')[0:50:1].aggregate(Avg('level'))
```

Comment: @Vicki: thanks. Unfortunately it returns **'list' object has no attribute 'aggregate'** :) Would have been awesome if it worked!